# Auto-increment the ID in an html table with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a basic table structure:

```
<tr>
   <th>ID</th>
   <th>Name</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>John</td>
</td>
```

My javascript function:

```
function newRow() {

  var tbodyRef = document.getElementById('myTable').getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];
  var lastRow = tbodyRef.rows[tbodyRef.rows.length - 1];
  var lastCell = lastRow.cells[lastRow.cells.length -1];

  // Insert a row at the end of table
  var newRow = tbodyRef.insertRow();
  
  // Insert a cell at the end of the row
  var newCell = newRow.insertCell();
  newCell.innerHTML = lastCell.id++;
  newCell = newRow.insertCell();
  newCell.innerHTML = "Alex";
}
```

Currently calling the function only generates '0' in ID column, how can I increment it?

Comment: You can use a loop

Comment: Use `innerText` not `innerHTML` if you don't explicitly need to insert HTML elements, since it's much faster and avoids accidentally injecting foreign HTML.

Comment: please add a "console.log(lastCell.id);" after "newCell.innerHTML = lastCell.id++;" and post it to see the content of lastCell.id

Comment: Do you even need the ID at that point? If your using a table for your data, then you are obviously using an array. Is there any special requirements stopping you from using the items index within the array as the ID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to run the following:

```
function newRow() {

  var tbodyRef = document.getElementById('myTable').getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];
  var lastRow = tbodyRef.rows[tbodyRef.rows.length - 1];
  var lastCell = lastRow.cells[lastRow.cells.length - 1];

  // Insert a row at the end of table
  var newRow = tbodyRef.insertRow();
  
  // Insert a cell at the end of the row
  var newCell = newRow.insertCell();
  newCell.innerHTML = lastRow.rowIndex+1;
  newCell = newRow.insertCell();
  newCell.innerHTML = "Alex";
}
```

A working example with JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/o30gxeda/1/

Answer (score 0):

Check my below snippet I used `Template Literals` and `querySelector()` method with easy way to achieve and count `rows length` and `increment by 1`.
*Helpful Link:*
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_string_templates.asp
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_queryselector.asp

```js
function newRow() {
    var tbodyRef = document.querySelector('#myTable tbody');
    tbodyRef.innerHTML+=`
    <tr>
        <td>${tbodyRef.rows.length + 1}</td>
        <td>Alex</td>
    </tr>`;
}
```

```html
<table id="myTable" width="100%" border="1" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th align="left">ID</th>
            <th align="left">Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>John</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<br>
<button type="button" onclick="newRow()">Add New Records</button>
```